# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forRawClass

Tags: spring

Whenever I build or run my JUnit test cases I get the below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forRawClass
```

After debugging I could see that the class `DefaultListableBeanfactory.getBeanNamesforTypes()` throws the exception and the method `forRAWclass` is also not resolved .

The *spring dependencies* that are in library are *4.3.7* and *4.1.0*. I tried to delete one of them but it is impacting my other java files.

Can someone please help me here to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check your classpath for duplicate dependencies of spring. You need to keep one version. either 4.3.7 or 4.1.0. If you see errors by removing one version you need to fix them.

Comment: I have only one dependency for spring core and that is 4.1 but for spring beans I have both

Comment: can you remove one of them and fix the issue that you see ?